# Get a list of user teams using MS bot framework

Tags: c#, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a bot for MS Teams.

Can I get a list of teams that the user is a member of, using the context from the private conversation message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nazariy Perepichka When a user sends a message to the bot, the payload received by the bot contains the aadObjectId of the user who has sent the message. This will be listed under `activity.From.AadObjectId.`
You could use that id to make a graph API call to [get the list of teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that the user is part of. Please try this and let us know if you face any issues.